# Angular 6 tslint duplicates every warning and error

Tags: angular, typescript, tslint, angular6

I've recently updated to Angular 6 and now every tslint error and warning is being duplicated. Tslint version is 5.10.0, Angular CLI is 6.0.0, Typescript is 2.7.2 and Codelyzer is 4.3.0. For example:

```
ERROR: file.ts[30, 58]: Missing trailing comma 
ERROR: file.ts[30, 58]: Missing trailing comma 
ERROR: file.ts[33, 29]: Missing semicolon 
ERROR: file.ts[33, 29]: Missing semicolon
```

Has anybody faced similar issues?

Comment: Some people reported this, This might be issue with the upgrade. `ts-lint` might resolve it soon.

Comment: Where did you find the reports on this? I'm asking because the only thing I found was this -> https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/5259 and it's from 2017. But it actually seems an issue with `ts-lint` indeed because Angular CLI now supports multiple projects and it goes through imports when reading `spec` files, thus finding the same error/warning again.

Comment: Having the same issue with the same versions except for angular 6.0.3.

Answer (score 1):

FWIW, in case anyone else comes across this issue. I had this same issue, it turned out to be that I had multiple TSLINT extensions enabled in VSCode (one for M$ and one from egamma). So it would display errors and warnings twice. Once I disabled one of them it only displays the errors and warnings once as intended.

Hope that helps.